# Change Url login logout according language site version

Tags: php, wordpress

In the beginning i say im totally amature of php . But i try to start my website . 
My problem is . When user choose english version of site ,and press log in url redirect him to homepage polish version . I want to make condition that when I login from english version url redirect me to homepage english version and logout to homepage english version and same for polish .

This is my site. 
http://www.elefantti.iq.pl/

This is my code in php (wordpress)

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo '<a href="'. wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ) .'" title="'. __('Log out') .'" class="zaloguj">' 
            . __('Log out') 
            . '</a>';
} else {
    echo '<a href="/zaloguj" title="'. __('Log in') .'" class="zaloguj">'
            . __('Log in') 
            . '</a>';
}
```

## ?>

```
<?php
global $polylang;

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
       if($polylang->pll_get_current_language(false)->slug == 'en') {

           echo '<a href="'. wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ) .'" title="'. __('Log out') .'" class="zaloguj">' 
            . __('Log out') 
            . '</a>';
       }else{
          echo '<a href="'. wp_logout_url('www.elefantti.iq.pl/pl/portfolio/') .'" title="'. __('wyloguj') .'" class="zaloguj">' 
            . __('wyloguj') 
            . '</a>';
       }

    } else {
        if($polylang->pll_get_current_language(false)->slug == 'en') {

 echo '<a href=" www.elefantti.iq.pl/en/login/" title="'. __('Log in') .'" class="zaloguj">'
            . __('Log in') 
            . '</a>';
        }else{
              echo '<a href="www.elefantti.iq.pl/pl/portfolio/" title="'. __('zaloguj') .'" class="zaloguj">'
            . __('zaloguj') 
            . '</a>';
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Thank You for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check current language of site then based on that you can redirect pages like

```
    <?php
global $polylang;

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
       if($polylang->pll_get_current_language(false)->slug == 'en') {

           echo '<a href="'. wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ) .'" title="'. __('Log out') .'" class="zaloguj">' 
            . __('Log out') 
            . '</a>';
       }else{
          echo '<a href="'. wp_logout_url( poslish page permalink ) .'" title="'. __('Log out in polish') .'" class="zaloguj">' 
            . __('Log out  polish') 
            . '</a>';
       }

    } else {
        if($polylang->pll_get_current_language(false)->slug == 'en') {

 echo '<a href="/zaloguj" title="'. __('Log in') .'" class="zaloguj">'
            . __('Log in') 
            . '</a>';
        }else{
              echo '<a href="polish page link" title="'. __('Log in  polish') .'" class="zaloguj">'
            . __('Log in  polish') 
            . '</a>';
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: can you write code more specificy almost like quick fix beacuse im a amature of php i dont know what to write to comments you do

Comment: which plugin are you using for language.

Comment: I dont know what i have to insert in upper polish page permalink ?. 
Rest i think understand.

Comment: polish page permalink means that polish version of page

Comment: I first post i add your code with my url link can you check it . Beacuse when i past it to code page is blank .
English version login is :  http://www.elefantti.iq.pl/en/login/
Logout: http://www.elefantti.iq.pl/en/home-page/

Comment: Polish login is : http://www.elefantti.iq.pl/zaloguj
logout is :  http://www.elefantti.iq.pl/

Comment: you can debug code and check where error is coming.

Comment: Yatendra - if I know PHP better i dont ask enyone for help . But this for mi is black magic . And have no idea why this code dosent' work proply. Thats why i ask you can you take a look and maybe modyfi it , it will be very helpfull for me.

Comment: Yes not quiet , but your Code help me , Thank You .
Can i ask you something , i have to click two times on enhlisg flag to change button name for english can you look at it 
http://www.elefantti.iq.pl/strona-glowna/

Comment: And one more  question , i have default portoflio in my theme . And can't categorized gallerys on polish version and english version . I have created all and all ale display in polish and english . Is possible to make it categorize for polish and other for english ? Now in site is only polish .